# Why 'all this code' instead of 'all these codes'?

Tags: usage, uncountable-nouns

Sometimes I encountered the form ***all this + singular noun*** instead of ***all these plural nouns*** when it is obvious to mention not a single entity but a number of things. Why? Is it a kind of simplification, or something like that?

> The growing complexity of computer software has direct implications
> for our global safety and security, particularly as the physical
> objects upon which we depend ― things like cars, airplanes, bridges,
> tunnels, and implantable medical devices ― transform themselves into
> computer code. Physical things are increasingly becoming information
> technologies. Cars are "computers we ride in," and airplanes are
> nothing more than "flying Solaris boxes attached to bucketfuls of
> industrial control systems."
>  As ***all this code*** grows in size and complexity, so too do the
> number of errors and software bugs. According to a study by Carnegie
> Mellon University, commercial software typically has twenty to thirty
> bugs for every thousand lines of code ― 50 million lines of code means
> 1 million to 1.5 million potential errors to be exploited. This is the
> basis for all malware attacks that take advantage of these computer
> bugs to get the code to do something it was not originally intended to
> do. As computer code grows more elaborate, software bugs flourish and
> security suffers, with increasing consequences for society at large.

[Future Crimes: Inside The Digital Underground and the Battle For Our ...](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=p6YTBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=Physical%20things%20are%20increasingly%20becoming%20information%20technologies.%20Cars%20are%20%E2%80%9Ccomputers%20we%20ride%20in,%E2%80%9D%20and%20airplanes%20are%20nothing%20more%20than%20%E2%80%9Cflying%20Solaris%20boxes%20attached%20to%20bucketfuls%20of%20industrial%20control%20systems.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=ORGJ9RBxcZ&sig=ACfU3U1UAboQLXRog5GplNjBmy0L98mscg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMz9PxjcCDAxW4aPUHHUEYCXA4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Physical%20things%20are%20increasingly%20becoming%20information%20technologies.%20Cars%20are%20%E2%80%9Ccomputers%20we%20ride%20in%2C%E2%80%9D%20and%20airplanes%20are%20nothing%20more%20than%20%E2%80%9Cflying%20Solaris%20boxes%20attached%20to%20bucketfuls%20of%20industrial%20control%20systems.%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Comment: This question should not be closed.

Comment: Agreed. It might be nice to expand it a bit to clarify, though. As I see it your question is not simply about the word "code," but about using noncount nouns to refer to multiple (countable) scenarios. It could be the same with other words, like "Bobby was gleeful. Charlie was elated. All *this happiness* was exhausting." Why singular "happiness" instead of plural, when there are two cases being discussed? Because "happiness" is still typically noncount.

Answer (score 7):

It's just because computer code is a so-called "noncount noun." Although the passage describes several contexts that use code, we wouldn't call each one "a code." (There are other ways of referring to specific sets of code, like "a code base.")

"Code" could be a "countable noun" for other usages, like "The Code of Hammurabi" or "Disarm the security system by entering one of the authorized codes."

Comment: This is correct for the mainstream use in programming. Outside of computer science, though, there are scientific fields which use the plural "codes" to refer to pieces of software. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20490/2947

Comment: People talk about computer code all the time, uncountable. So, this answer is RIGHT. :)